# Sort Multiple Objects By Common Element

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have four lists of different object types. Each object type shares a common element: getTime().

Notes:

1. Lists are in order but may not start at the same point.
2. Lists may not start at the same point in time.

What is the best way for me to order these 4 objects such that each element "i" has the same value for getTime()?

Comment: The best way? So you have already implemented I am guessing a Collections.sort with a comparator on getTime?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Given two lists with time values: a=[ 1, 3, 5 ] and b=[ 2, 3, 4 ], what is the result?  My guess is: a'= [ 1, null, 3, null, 5 ] and b'= [ null, 2, 3, 4, null ].  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by same element for `getTime()` you mean cross reference the lists to match elements having the same time...

I would create a wrapper class with 2 methods, `getTime()` and `getValue()`

```
public class TimeElement{ 
    final long time;
    final Object value;
    TimeElement(long time, Object value){
        this.time = time;
        this.value = value;
    }    
    public long getTime(){return time;}
    public Object getValue(){return value;}
}
```

Then, create one large list by adding the contents of each list.

```
List<TimeElement> list = new ArrayList<TimeElement>();
for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
    list.add(new TimeElement(list1.get(i).getTime(), list1.get(i));
}
```

Then, sort this combined list. Iterate over it and you'll be able to easily get elements with the same value for time.

Answer (score -1):

You can sort the first list by time however you want.  Then for the other three lists, you can simply iterate over the first list, and find the object in the other lists with the same time.

```
for (Object1 o : list1) {
    for(Object2 o2 : list2) {
        if ((o2.getTime()).equals(o.getTime())) {
            newList2.add(o2);
            break;
        }
    }
    for(Object3 o3 : list3) {
        if ((o3.getTime()).equals(o.getTime())) {
            newList3.add(o3);
            break;
        }
    }
    for(Object4 o4 : list4) {
        if ((o4.getTime()).equals(o.getTime())) {
            newList2.add(o4);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```